# Authentication to Google Drive from external web application

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have an asp.net MVC application that is supposed to interact with Google Drive that I am building. I receive a fileId from my UI and pass it to the controller as shown below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void DownloadFile(string fileId)
    {
        FileService fileService = new FileService();
        DriveService driveService = new DriveService();
        fileService.GetFileMetaDataInfo(driveService, fileId);
        Console.WriteLine(fileId);
    }

public class FileService
{
    public void GetFileMetaDataInfo(DriveService service, String fileId)
    {
        try
        {
            Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Fetch();
            Console.WriteLine("Title: " + file.Title);
            Console.WriteLine("Description: " + file.Description);
            Console.WriteLine("MIME type: " + file.MimeType);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The controller then passes control to the FileService class which is also shown above. At the basic level for now I just want to be able to see if I am able to get the file's MetaDataInfo from google drive. This code throws an exception at the point it attempts to get the file details, the 1st line in the try block. I suspect this has to do with authentication. This is where I need help, I have looked at the Drive API documentation and I am not quite clear on how to authenticate from my external web application to Google Drive. Could anyone clarify this for me, or possible show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message should tell you why the request is failing, but I agree with you the problem is with authentication as I don't see where you set your credentials.

The Google Drive SDK documentation includes a complete ASP.NET MVC application that you can use as reference:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet